# BigQuery LAST_VALUE With Condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the sample data below and I am looking to populate the value in the expectedOutput column. I want it to be calculated according to the rule -- if isValid = 1, give me the fruit value the last time isValid = 1. So in this example, row 1 is null because that is the first value. Row 6 shows apple because this row is valid and apple was the fruit the last time there was a valid value.

```
row           fruit       isValid     expectedOutput (Prior valid value)
1             apple       1           NULL
2             apple       0           NULL
3             apple       0           NULL
4             apple       0           NULL
5             orange      0           NULL
6             orange      1           apple
7             grape       1           orange
8             grape       0           NULL
```

Here's what I've tried, doesn't quite get me the right result.

```
LAST_VALUE(case when isValid = 1 then fruit end IGNORE NULLS) OVER(PARTITION BY all ORDER BY row)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add bounds to your window to exclude the current row :

```sql
ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
```

Try this:

```
WITH
  table1 AS (
        SELECT 1 as row,  'apple'  as fruit,  1 as  isValid  union all
        SELECT 2 as row,  'apple'  as fruit,  0 as  isValid  union all
        SELECT 3 as row,  'apple'  as fruit,  0 as  isValid  union all
        SELECT 4 as row,  'apple'  as fruit,  0 as  isValid  union all
        SELECT 5 as row,  'orange' as fruit,  0 as  isValid  union all 
        SELECT 6 as row,  'orange' as fruit,  1 as  isValid  union all 
        SELECT 7 as row,  'grape'  as fruit,  1 as  isValid  union all   
        SELECT 8 as row,  'grape'  as fruit,  0 as  isValid
)

SELECT
  *,
  CASE
    WHEN isValid = 1 THEN LAST_VALUE(IF(isValid=1, fruit, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) OVER(ORDER BY row ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING)
  END AS expectedOutput
FROM
  table1
```

Answer (score 1):

See example below

```
#standardSQL
with `project.dataset.table` as (
  select 1 row , 'apple' fruit, 1 isValid union all
  select 2, 'apple', 0 union all
  select 3, 'apple', 0 union all
  select 4, 'apple', 0 union all
  select 5, 'orange', 0 union all
  select 6, 'orange', 1 union all
  select 7, 'grape', 1 union all
  select 8, 'grape', 0 
)
select *, 
  if(isValid = 1, lag(fruit) over(partition by isValid order by row), null) as Prior_valid_value
from `project.dataset.table` 
# order by row
```

with output

[image]